# Send adonis mail data to the edge view

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I want to send arrangements or variables to iterate and get in the view that I'm going to send in the email. I'm using adonis.js, then left the code of how I'm sending the mail.

What do I need to send variables or arrangements and get them in the view emails.test?

```
await Mail.send('emails.prueba', data, (message) => {
        message
            .from('myemail@.com')
            .to(data.email)
            .subject('Alerts')
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should read the [docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/mail), it's all described there. So if you take a look at the [Mail API](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/mail#_mail_api) you can pass a data object to the view.

```
await Mail.send('view', data, (message) => {
  message
    .from('')
    .to('')
})
```

So to pass the variable `foo` to the view you would have something like this

```
const foo = 'bar';
await Mail.send('emails.hello', foo, (message) => {
  message
    .from('')
    .to('')
})
```

In your `emails/hello.edge` template you can call this variable with `{{ foo }}`